# Protractor - element click is not working

Tags: protractor, angularjs-ng-click

My element looks like this:

```
<div id="searchBarFilters">
  <div class="filterBox">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <h3>Adjust Filters<span ng-click="closeGlobalFilters()" class="icon-close"></h3>
        <hr/>
```

When the user clicks on this close icon, the particular div panel visibility is hidden. I am checking this functionality using protractor as below:

```
browser.driver.findElement(by.css('span[ng-click*="closeGlobalFilters()"][class="icon-close"]')).click();
```

I had to use both the attributes of span tag because there are 2 other elements with the same className.

The above code is not showing any error but I do not see the click action eing executed in action.

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: If you add a `console.log("test");` at first line of your closeGlobalFilters function, do you see that trace in the console output when test is running ?

Comment: @Antikhippe, I do not have access to the closeGlobalFilters function code.

Comment: More information should be included. What is happening right before you want to click the object? Does it appear after a field is inputted? Could you provide more html around your span? Maybe there's a different way to select it.

Comment: @cnishina: I have appended the html code surrounding the span tag.